# failed to fetch update caused by wine

Tags: appcenter, wine

[image: when i open appcenter a popup message is appeared as shown in the pic.Anyone knows what the poroblem is?]

when i open appcenter a popup message is appeared as shown in the pic.Anyone knows what the poroblem is?]

Answer (score 1):

Your WINE repository is very old and deprecated (see [here](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-wine/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)) and does not have proper update packages for your OS. To fix this issue, first remove this PPA from your system:

`sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`

and then add the newer WINE PPA:

`wget https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/Release.key`

`sudo apt-key add Release.key`

`sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'`

`sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

when i try to execute
[image] sudo apt-add-repository 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu/'
 it shows
  " 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/gnome3/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/wine/wine-builds/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details." And hence i cannot execute apt-get update